# How to change intel xdk editor theme?

Tags: intel-xdk

I am using intel xdk tool for my mobile app project, now i want to change the editor theme/ background color.
[image]

```
   I Need to change this **white background color** to some other, also visit some docs regarding this but could not find.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are themes available as extensions.

Click the File menu (of the Brackets Editor), select Extension Manager, then click the Themes tab to browse the list of themes and install the one you like.

After installation which is really fast, close the Themes window, then click the View menu, select Themes and choose the theme you have just installed from the list. Enjoy!

[See Themes Page Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRsGd.jpg)